# How to not repeat code in Swift for attributes of button?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uibutton

I am new to IOS Development. I am creating an app with a lot of buttons. How do I give the same attributes to all the buttons with help of a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer really isn't ideal for stackoverflow since it's not a direct problem your looking for help with, but instead a question of best practice. Check the code of conduct again.

However you can do the following:

(If you need those buttons to be instanced/complete right away)

a) Create a private static function in your class which builds your buttons with the attributes, and gives them the text and selector you pass via parameters.

b) Create a private static function which only applies the attributes you require

(If you just want to apply the same style)

a) Create a private function in your class which stylises all buttons upon viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could try:

1 - You could try and create a subclass of `UIButton` with the common styling code, and use that custom button in your program instead of UIButton.

2 - You can extend UIButton to have a styling category function, then call that function from `viewDidLoad()` in your view controller or `awakeFromNib()` in your view.

3 - You could use the appearance protocol to style some aspects of the button (though it can be a bit limiting).

The approach you choose to do and how you choose to develop is something you need to decide as a developer.